# got Highcharts error #13 when running unit test

Tags: reactjs, testing, highcharts

The highcharts render fine in browser without error, but when running test on the component, I got test failing:

● renders correctly

```
Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13

  22 | 
  23 |     highChartsRender(options) {
> 24 |         Highcharts.chart(this.props.id,{
     |                    ^
  25 |             chart: {
  26 |               type: "line",
  27 |               renderTo: "lineChart",
```

and in my HCLineChart.test.js file, I have this:

```
it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = TestRenderer
    .create(<HCLineChart title={title} options={options} id={"LineChart1"} />)
    .toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

and then in my HCLineChart.js file, I have this:

```
import React from "react";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HC_exporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
import HC_exporting_data from "highcharts/modules/export-data";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class HCLineChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);       
        HC_exporting(Highcharts);
        HC_exporting_data(Highcharts);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.highChartsRender(this.props.options);
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        this.highChartsRender(nextProps.options);
        return false;
    }

    highChartsRender(options) {
        Highcharts.chart(this.props.id,{
            chart: {
            type: "line",
            renderTo: "lineChart",
            height: 500,
            },
            title: {
                text: this.props.title,
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: options.xAxisCategories,
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: this.props.title,
                },
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                    },
                },
            },
            credits:{
                enabled: false,
            },
            exporting: {
                buttons: {
                    contextButton: {
                        enabled: true,
                        menuItems: [
                            "printChart",
                            "downloadCSV",
                            "downloadXLS",
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
            series: options.data,
        });

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            lang: {
                thousandsSep: ",",
            },
        });
    }

    render() {
        return <div className="line-chart" id={this.props.id} />;
    }
}

export default HCLineChart;
```

So why I got the error only in testing? I saw the div already there before calling the Highchart.chart ?

Thank you.

Lei

Comment: Hi @Lei, The problem is definitely related with the container. Please check if the container already exist and try to use direct reference to the element instead of id reference.

Comment: I tried to change      return (<div className="line-chart" id={this.props.id} />);       
 TO                 return (<div><div className="line-chart" ref={ref => this.container = ref} /></div>);   and change the Highcharts.chart(this.container),{}) . it gets another error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null" when run testing......I"m run out of idea ...,,

Comment: It looks very strange, I do not know how exactly your tests work, but it seems to me that your code should work correctly. You can check your case with `highcharts-react-official` wrapper: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/50629lo8xl

Comment: @Lei Did your problem solved? I am also facing the same problem for react-highcharts snapshot testing